# How to fit the tabs in bottom on ionic1.0.0_beta.14

Tags: android, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

And here you can see the tabs are at the top. This is how tabs will look on an Android device by default.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in the Ionic Tabs documentation and the related $IonicConfigProvider documentation it is possible to specify a tabs.position config item. This can be done as per this code extract.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
```

For more details: [More detail about $ionicConfigProvider](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider)